# Calculate percentage of revenue per month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sum, percentage

I have the following underlying data:

```
+-------+-------+---------------+
| Order | Month | sqft produced |
+-------+-------+---------------+
|  1001 |     4 | 10.29         |
|  1001 |     6 | 4'367.66      |
|  1001 |     7 | 203.57        |
|  1001 |     8 | 294.61        |
|  1001 |     9 | 92.28         |
|  1001 |    10 | 34.47         |
|  1001 |    12 | 16.59         |
|  1002 |     1 | 1.74          |
|  1002 |     4 | 19.54         |
|  1002 |     7 | 5'552.21      |
|  1002 |     9 | 309.62        |
|  1002 |    10 | 24.15         |
|  1002 |    12 | 52.16         |
|  1003 |     5 | 807.45        |
+-------+-------+---------------+
```

Those are three orders and I want to split the revenue according to the percentage of sqft produced in each month.

The revenue table:

```
+-------+-----------+
| Order |  Revenue  |
+-------+-----------+
|  1001 | 1'135'465 |
|  1002 | 1'773'499 |
|  1003 | 172'633   |
+-------+-----------+
```

So the output of the query should look like this:

```
+-------+-------+------------------+
| Order | Month | Revenue produced |
+-------+-------+------------------+
|  1001 |     4 | 2'327.72         |
|  1001 |     6 | 988'017.67       |
|  1001 |     7 | 46'050.00        |
|  1001 |     8 | 66'644.36        |
|  1001 |     9 | 20'874.86        |
|  1001 |    10 | 7'797.53         |
|  1001 |    12 | 3'752.86         |
|  1002 |     1 | 517.82           |
|  1002 |     4 | 5'815.02         |
|  1002 |     7 | 1'652'314.97     |
|  1002 |     9 | 92'141.64        |
|  1002 |    10 | 7'186.94         |
|  1002 |    12 | 15'522.60        |
|  1003 |     5 | 172'633.00       |
+-------+-------+------------------+
```

I am struggling with a way of getting the underlying data in that format because I can't seem to be able to split it by month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the percentage via dividing the square footage over the sum of the square footage partitioned over the [Order] would get you what you are looking for:

```
select p.[Order], 
       [Month], 
       Revenue, 
       [sqft produced], 
       CAST([sqft produced] / SUM([sqft produced]) OVER(PARTITION BY p.[Order]) AS DECIMAL(10,5)) * 100 as sqft_percentage, 
       Revenue * CAST([sqft produced] / SUM([sqft produced]) OVER(PARTITION BY p.[Order]) AS DECIMAL(10,5)) as revenue_produced
FROM [Orders] p
INNER JOIN Revenue r
ON r.[Order] = p.[Order]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the first table `sqft` and the second `revenues`. To avoid reserved words, the first table column's  names will be:

```
order_id, month_num, sqft_produced
```

The second:

```
order_id, total_revenue
```

The SQL for what you need goes something like this (this is for Oracle):

```
SELECT order_id, month_num, (sqft_produced / total_sqft * total_revenue) revenue_produced
FROM sqft INNER JOIN
(SELECT order_id, total_sqft, total_revenue FROM (
(SELECT order_id, sum(sqft_produced) total_sqft
GROUP BY order_id) sqfts INNER JOIN revenues ON sqfts.order_id = revenues.order_id)) totals
ON sqft.order_id = totals.order_id;
```

Step by step:

```
SELECT order_id, sum(sqft_produced) total_sqft
GROUP BY order_id;
```

This gets you total square feet produced by order.

```
(SELECT order_id, sum(sqft_produced) total_sqft
GROUP BY order_id) sqfts INNER JOIN revenues ON sqfts.order_id = revenues.order_id;
```

This gets you a table with total revenues and total square feet.

And then you join this table to your sqft table and divide the square feet produced each month by total square feet and multiply by total revenue, thus splitting the revenue proportionally to square feet.